# Find function in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

When we have the following:

```
tweet2 = 'Want cheap snacks? Visit @cssu office in BA2283'
```

`print(tweet2[tweet2.find('cheap')])` results in the output `'c'` and I cant wrap my head around how it does this. I tried the visualizer and it didn't show anything. Could anyone please explain?

Comment: `tweet2.find('cheap')` returns the index at which the beginning of "cheap" is found, and when that index is used in `tweet2[index]`, it returns the character at that index, which is "c"

Comment: `tweet2.find('cheap')` returns the index `'cheap'` is first found, which is 5. `tweet2[5]` is `c`

Comment: @BenLindsay please write a real answer.

Comment: @Soviut I actually found their answer the most helpful!

Comment: @Stackstack I meant they should write an answer and not a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tweet2.find('cheap')` returns the index at which the beginning of "cheap" is found, and when that index is used in `tweet2[index]`, it returns the character at that index, which is "c"

Comment: Ah so initially, find.() finds the index of the beginning of the string and this index gets passed into tweet2[...], thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

It's because the find(str, string) method determines if str occurs in string, or in a substring of string and returns the position of first occurrence. So when you call `tweet2.find('cheap')` it will return the **position** that is the first occurs of cheap.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider reading python documentation on string methods and lists

```
# define string variable tweet2
tweet2 = 'Want cheap snacks? Visit @cssu office in BA2283'
# find position of substring 'cheap', which is 5 (strings has 0-based indices in python
n = tweet2.find('cheap')
# print 5th element of string, which is 'c'
print(tweet2[n])
```

Answer (score 0):

`find` returns an index, not a slice.

If you want the full string you can get it like so:

```
to_find = 'cheap'
ind = tweet2.find(to_find)
print(tweet2[ind:ind+len(to_find)])
```